# Prove that if $a$ and $b$ are real numbers with $0 < a < b$ then $\frac{1}{b} < \frac{1}{a}$

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, solution-verification

> Suppose a and b are real numbers. Prove that if $0 < a < b$
>   then $\frac{1}{b} < \frac{1}{a}$.

My attempt:

Given that $0<<$

We can write $b$ as $b = an$, where $n>1$
$$\tag1\frac{1}{a} = \frac{n}{an} = \frac{n}{b} $$
$$\tag2\frac{n}{b} > \frac{1}{b} \implies \frac{1}{a} > \frac{1}{b}$$

Is it correct?

Comment: Note that the variable letter $n$ is often used for variables that only take _integer_ values. Here you need your $n$ to be an arbitrary real number, which might confuse a reader. You could avoid that by calling it, for example, $c$ or $x$ instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, your solution is correct.

Of course you could have multiplied both sides of your inequality by $$\frac {1}{ab}$$ to get the result in one shot.